# WooCommerce REST API - Retrieve Order Attributes (Size / Color)

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, api, woocommerce

Using the [WooCommerce REST Client Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/blob/master/example/example.php), I can easily pull orders that are in processing, like so:

```
$response = $wc_api->get_orders( array( 'status' => 'processing' ) );
```

But the results do NOT include Attributes (color, size, etc.) even though the purchased product was setup with Size/Color attributes that correlate with product variations. That part all works just fine. The customer can select the size and color of a product, but that information does NOT show up with a `get_orders` query.

Here's what does show up:

```
<line_items>
     <XML_Serializer_Tag>
         <id>18</id>
         <subtotal>19.99</subtotal>
         <total>19.99</total>
         <total_tax>0.00</total_tax>
         <price>19.99</price>
         <quantity>1</quantity>
         <tax_class />
         <name>Cool T-Shirt You Just Bought!</name>
         <product_id>351</product_id>
         <sku>194953</sku>
     </XML_Serializer_Tag>
 </line_items>
```

As you can see, even though the customer has selected "Large / Black" for the variations, it does not show up in the `get_orders` data.

I can pull the available attributes for the **product** using the same library, but I need to pull the customer-selected attributes for the **order**.

Comment: I am talking from Magento experience , same might apply to woocommerce : you need to get the order's products and from that collection/array you can get product's details like `weight` and `size`

Comment: I **can** access product details from the REST API; for example, I can have it give me the available `color` options for a particular product. But that doesn't tell me what `color` the customer chose when the order was placed. The REST API doesn't appear to offer that data, nor the selected `size` nor any other 'variable' data fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate answering my own question, but it turns out the answer is quite simple:

The [WooCommerce REST Client Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/blob/master/example/example.php) has not been updated for V2 of the API, even though WooCommerce links it as a V2 resource. The solution is extremely simple:

Navigate to ~/class-wc-api-client.php and change line 17 to:

`const API_ENDPOINT = 'wc-api/v2/';`

The API immediately returned the correct data when I did a get_orders() query.

Answer (score 2):

again I am talking from magento background `who would like to get that bounty :P`
I think you must process each order separately form your list of orders you generated above

quoting this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97176/get-product-id-from-order-id-in-woocommerce)

you can get the order items of an order by

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
```

then if you loop through them, you can get all the relevant data:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    //// you had the product id now you can load the product and get all information  you might need 
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you were doing it from within the Wordpress / WooCommerce framework, this would be the way to do it -- maybe as a plugin. But the REST API doesn't provide such direct access to WC_Order, and it's the REST API I'm trying to work with.